# Why is a cast needed here?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been working through Apple's "Your Second IOS App" tutorial" and I've noticed that every time I use an `NSDateFormatter` for producing a date string I am expected to cast the input date object.

e.g. ([Page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/CustomizingDetailView/CustomizingDetailView.html) - under "To implement the configureView method")

```
BirdSighting *theSighting = self.sighting;

if (theSighting) {
    self.birdNameLabel.text = [theSighting name];
    self.locationLabel.text = [theSighting location];

    self.dateLabel.text = [formatter stringFromDate:(NSDate *)theSighting.date]; // Here
}
```

However I know that in the `BirdSighting` class that the `date` property is always an `NSDate` object.

So I was wondering why the tutorial always casts the input, is there some sort of objective-c convention or framework convetion that recommends that you do this? and if so why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not necessary. The cast is simply for clarity, as the property is already defined as a `NSDate`, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/DesigningDataModel/DesigningDataModel.html):

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *date;
```

The only situation where a cast would be necessary in that form would either be in non-arc when dealing with core foundation, like this:

```
CFDateRef asCFDate;
NSDate *asNSDate = (NSDate *) asCFDate;
```

However, in ARC, you would use a `__bridge` cast instead.

Answer (score 2):

The cast is unnecessary and should be removed in my opinion.

The property is already defined as an `NSDate` on the data model object (unless there is a later step that redefines it to `id` or something, which is doubtful) so it is giving no extra information to readers of the code or the compiler.

Comment: Even if it was a `id`, the cast is still unnecessary, as all pointers to objects "subclass" (notice the air quotes) the `struct objc_object`, and can be implicitly converted between each other. The only place where a cast would be necessary would be if dealing with an opaque struct, such as in `CoreFoundation` or `CoreGraphics`.

Comment: I meant necessary in terms of code clarity rather than compilation, but you're absolutely right (as usual!)